# How to delete Single-field indexes that generated automatically by firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**update:

   TLDR;**
if you reached here, you should recheck the way you build your DB. 
Your document(s) probably gets expended over time (due to nested list or etc.).

**Original question:**
I have a collection of documents that have a lot of fields. I do not query documents even no simple queries-
I am using only-

```
db.collection("mycollection").doc(docName).get().then(....);
```

in order to read the docs,
so I don't need any indexing for this collection.

The issue is that firestore generates Single-field indexes automatically, and due to the amount of fields cause limitation exceeding  of indexing:
[image]
And if I trying to add a field to one of the documents it throws me an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Too many indexed properties for entity: app: "s~myapp",path <  Element {    type: "tags",    name: "aaaa"  }>
    at new FirestoreError (index.cjs.js:346)
    at index.cjs.js:6058
    at W.<anonymous> (index.cjs.js:6003)
    at Ab (index.js:23)
    at W.g.dispatchEvent (index.js:21)
    at Re.Ca (index.js:98)
    at ye.g.Oa (index.js:86)
    at dd (index.js:42)
    at ed (index.js:39)
    at ad (index.js:37)
```

I couldn't find any way to delete these single-field-indexing or to tell firestore to stop generating them.
I found this in firestore console:
[image]

but there is no way to disable this, and to disable auto indexing for a specific collection. 
Any way to do it?

Comment: Could you please share the code you wrote along with the data you are inserting that causes the error?

Comment: it was simple update:
db.collection("myCollection").doc("myDoc").update({....});
but this error was only the syptom the real problem is to cancel the auto indexing, made by firestore.

Comment: It is not possible to cancel the default indexing. The question is why are you reaching the limit and getting an error. What is passed to the `update` function? I use Firestore daily and never got such an issue. For sure, it depends of the context but without more information it's hard to suggest something.

Comment: There is *now* a way to do it. The question still remains. There's already an answer that fits the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete simple Indexes in Firestore [firestore](/questions/tagged/firestore).

See this answer for more up to date information on creating and deleting indexes.

[Firestore composite index permutation explosion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498492/firestore-composite-index-permutation-explosion/55651326#55651326)

If you go in to Indexes after selecting the firestore database and then select "single" indexes there is an Add exemption button which allows you to specify which fields in a Collection (or Sub-collection) have simple indexes generated by Firestore. You have to specify the Collection followed by the field. You then specify every field individually as you cannot specify a whole collection. There does not seem to be any checking on valid Collections or field names.

The only way I can think to check this has worked is to do a query using the field and it should fail.

I do this on large string fields which have normal text in them as they would take a long time to index and I know I will never search using this field.

Firestore creates two indexes for every simple field (ascending and descending) but it is also possible to create an exemption which removes one of these if you will never need the second one which helps improve performance and makes it less likely to hit the index limits. In addition you can select whether arrays are indexed or not. If you create a lot of entries it an Array, then this can very quickly hit the firestore limits on the number of indexes, so care has to be taken when using indexes and it will often be best to take the indexes off Arrays since the designer may have no control over how many Array data items are added with the result that the maximum index limit is reached and the application will get an error as the original poster explained.

You can also remove any simple indexes if you are not using them even if a field is included in a complex index. The complex index will still work.

Other things to keep an eye on.

If you are indexing a timestamp field (or any field that increases or decreases sequentially between documents) and you are not using this to force a sequence in queries, then there is a maximum write rate of 500 writes per second for the collection. In this case, this limit can be removed by removing the increasing and decreasing indexes.

Note that unlike the Realtime Database, fields created with Auto-ID do not guarantee any ordering as they are generated by firestore to spread writes and avoid hotspots or bottlenecks where all writes (and therefore reads) end up at a single location. This means that a timestamp is often needed to generate ordering but you may be able to design your collections / sub-collections data layout to avoid the need for a timestamp. For example, if you are using a timestamp to find the last document added to a collection, it might be better to just store the ID of the last document added.

Large array or map fields can also cause the 20,000 index entries per document limit to be reached, so you can exempt the array from indexing (see screenshot below).

[image]

Once you have added one exemption, then you will get this screen.
[image: Exemption screen once one has been added]

See this link as well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview

Comment: This is the right answer. In fact, as the (as of now) accepted answers says, the database needs to be restructured. But the question is about single-field indexes, not about structure.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't do that right now with Firebase. However, this is a good signal that you need to restructure your database models to avoid hitting limits such as the 1MB per document.

The documentation talks about the limitations on your data:

> You can't run queries on nested lists. Additionally, this isn't as
>   scalable as other options, especially if your data expands over time.
>   With larger or growing lists, the document also grows, which can lead
>   to slower document retrieval times.

See this page for more information about the advantages and disadvantages on the different strategies for structuring your data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data

Comment: The ability of running queries on nested documents should be definitely suggested as an enhancement or new feature.

Comment: There is a way to add single-field index exemptions. See the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52059677/8217812)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Firestore documentation:

> Cloud Firestore requires an index for every query, to ensure the best performance. All document fields are automatically indexed, so queries that only use equality clauses don't need additional indexes. If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

**Can you update your question with the structure data you are trying to save?**

A workaround for your problem would be to create compound indexes, or as a last resource, Firestore may not be suited to the needs for your app and [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) can be a better solution.

See tradeoffs:
[RTDB vs Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there currently exists the switch that you are looking for, so I think that leaves the following,

1. Globally disable built-in indexes and create all indexes explicitly.  Painful and they have limits too.
2. A workaround where you treat your Cloud Firestore unfriendly content like a BLOB, like so:

To store,

```
const objIn = {text: 'my object with a zillion fields' };
const jsonString  = JSON.stringify(this.objIn);
const container = { content: this.jsonString };
```

To retrieve,

```
const objOut = JSON.parse(container.content);
```

Comment: How do you globally disable built-in indexes? I only see the possibility to create an exception for a specific field.